# How to read an .rds file located in google drive using R?

Tags: r, google-drive-api, cloud

I need to load an rds file to a variable using R.
The publicly available rds file is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nWGXS0TBK-WrtKmAujuDLXA2xSSIl7fy/view?usp=share_link).

How do I load it into R

Comment: Does [Load an RDS file from the web (i.e. a url) directly into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840037/load-an-rds-file-from-the-web-i-e-a-url-directly-into-r) help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to generate the direct download link; in this particular case it would be `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nWGXS0TBK-WrtKmAujuDLXA2xSSIl7fy` ,
the pattern being `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={id}"` . There are also utility functions for this, `usethis::create_download_url()` for example. Then you can download it or create a connection object that `readRDS()` is able to read:

```r
gdrive_shared <- "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nWGXS0TBK-WrtKmAujuDLXA2xSSIl7fy/view"
usethis::create_download_url(gdrive_shared) |>
  url() |>
  readRDS() |>
  tibble::as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 1,980 × 57
#>    ANGPTL4 B3GNT5 CDK5R1 FKBP5 KIF13B KLF13  KLF3  KLF9 LRRC8A  PAG1  PDK4 RCOR3
#>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1    6.82   5.49   6.04  7.90   8.78  8.28  5.55  9.55   7.21  5.89  6.53  9.14
#>  2    8.74   5.40   6.71  9.99   7.60  7.65  5.17  9.55   6.91  6.09  7.21  8.24
#>  3    8.01   5.33   5.87  6.83   8.28  8.74  5.41  9.09   7.63  6.51  8.19  8.29
#>  4    6.18   5.66   6.37  7.40   9.72  8.15  5.11  9.06   6.88  5.97  6.85  9.39
#>  5    9.19   5.30   6.67  7.76   8.03  7.56  5.40  9.21   6.55  6.75  6.31  8.36
#>  6    6.94   5.39   6.20  6.74   9.44  8.31  5.23  8.50   7.29  5.82  8.35  8.59
#>  7    8.03   5.18   5.97  7.37   8.75  8.79  5.32  9.40   6.92  6.56  8.80  8.44
#>  8    8.01   5.12   6.34  8.52   7.29  8.87  5.58  8.70   7.61  6.24  6.52  8.14
#>  9    6.76   5.31   6.57  8.72   9.11  8.13  5.46  8.92   7.04  6.35  6.90  7.76
#> 10    6.74   5.60   6.59  8.51   7.94  8.76  5.51  8.72   7.06  6.89  5.75  7.60
#> # … with 1,970 more rows, and 45 more variables: RGCC <dbl>, RGS2 <dbl>,
#> #   SGK1 <dbl>, STON2 <dbl>, Mean <dbl>, ESR1 <dbl>, PGR <dbl>, AR <dbl>,
#> #   NR3C1 <dbl>, VDR <dbl>, AGE_AT_DIAGNOSIS <dbl>, OS_MONTHS <dbl>,
#> #   OS_STATUS <chr>, RFS_STATUS <chr>, RFS_MONTHS <dbl>, ER_STATUS <chr>,
#> #   HER2_STATUS <chr>, PR_STATUS <chr>, LYMPH_NODES_EXAMINED_POSITIVE <int>,
#> #   NPI <dbl>, CELLULARITY <chr>, CHEMOTHERAPY <chr>, COHORT <int>,
#> #   ER_IHC <chr>, HER2_SNP6 <chr>, HORMONE_THERAPY <chr>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>